# Unexpected file found in package directory lwc\jsconfig.json

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-error

On 12/13/2021, I attempted to run sfdx force:source:push -f to a scratch org. Since then I have been getting this 'Unexpected file found in package directory lwc\jsconfig.json' error every single time I attempt to use push my source to a scratch org:

```
ERROR running force:source:push:  Unexpected file found in package directory: C:\Salesforce IT Repo\Salesforce\src\smart\main\default\lwc\jsconfig.json
```

[image]

**Steps To Reproduce:**

1. Run `sfdx force:org:create -f` to create scratch org
2. Deploy metadata by running `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -f`
3. Run `sfdx force:source:push` -f to attempt to push source to default scratch org

**Expected result**

Source is successfully pushed to the default scratch org.

**Actual result**

The following error occurs:

```
ERROR running force:source:push: Unexpected file found in package directory: C:\Salesforce IT Repo\Salesforce\src\smart\main\default\lwc\jsconfig.json
```

**Additional information**

We have the `lwc\jsconfig.json` files in our `.forceignore`:
[image]

I can't point to anything in particular that could have caused this. We have scoured our commits since November, and no changes made on our end should have lead to this suddenly beginning to occur.

My colleagues and I have tried many, many different ways to try and get around this issue, including:

-Changing CLI version: CLI 7.129.x (npm), CLI 7.130.x (npm), CLI 7.131.x (npm), CLI 96.1.x (npm) and a Non-npm install: CLI 7.132.0

-Run scratch build against an older branch of ours (before this error began occurring)

-Delete the jsconfig.json file, which leads to a slew of other errors

-Cloning Salesforce project into new directory

-Clearing all temp files, appdata, etc related to SFDX and npm

-Uninstalling and deleting EVERYTHING locally relating to Salesforce, npm, SFDX, and VSCode

-And every combination of the above you can think of

The ONLY thing that we have found to get around this is to use the command `sfdx force:source:beta:push`, which DOES successfully push the data to the scratch org. However, this causes a lot of other issues with git AND I am unable to properly go through with our dev process because I run into errors when attempting to push to and pull from the default scratch org once changes have been made. So this is not a valid fix for our problem.

Weirdest part is that this is inconsistent across our team. We have half the team running into the issue, and half the team pushing data to scratch orgs just fine. We've tried going through and copying their settings, Extension versions, CLI versions, etc, AND compared our files to those who are functioning correctly, but nothing there has worked.

**Salesforce Extension Version in VS Code:**
Salesforce Extension Pack v53.12.0

**SFDX CLI Version:**
sfdx-cli/7.132.0 win32-x64 node-v16.13.1 (no extra plugins)

**OS and version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise

Any ideas on what could possibly be causing something like this? I don't quite understand why the .forceignore isn't actually ignoring the lwc/jsconfig.json.

Comment: Are you all using the same dev hub? If not, is there a difference in SF platform version between those who can and those who cannot? Alternatively, is there a difference in SF instance between those that can and those that cannot?

Comment: BTW why do you use mdapi deploy first, then source push, and how can you mix the two formats (mdapi and source)? That is weird.

Comment: Should you not be using / instead of backslash in the forceignore file for path separators? I understand backslash is what Windows uses but AFAIK you should be using the portable forward slash...

Comment: @PhilW Thank you for the ideas! Yes, we are all using the same dev hub. And no, I don't believe there is any difference in SF instance - a lot of us were all onboarded onto the team and provided access around the same time via the same exact process. With the mdapi deploy, a senior dev built out a script to build a scratch org, and that is the order that it is done in. We had no issues doing so previous to this. And I have tried both ways of using the backslash - what you see in the pic is what I changed it to. Originally it is /, but still getting the error.

Comment: I would re-visit that scripting if I were you; it seems very strange to use `force:mdapi:deploy` instead of `force:source:deploy`. Using the latter you can still "deploy" rather than push but from the source format structure (though TBH you probably should just use `force:source:push` since that avoids the need to use the -f since tracking status will be consistent from the word go).

Comment: That makes sense to look back into overall. Unfortunately, though, even after changing that portion of the script and running it again, I am getting the same error. Even ignoring the script and manually going through the process of creating an org and pushing data (etc) yields the same results. But thank you for the suggestion!